# User Access Control no longer opens

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-registry, uac

I can not run programs as Administrator, because I tried to do [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4820/how-to-really-completely-disable-uac-on-windows-7/), and modifying the value in the registry didn't do what I wanted to do, I thought that it would stop asking for passwords and let me run as an Admin whenever I wanted. Instead it just doesn't open the password prompt and runs as a normal user. I tried to change it back but I can't because I can't run Regedit as an Admin.

What I have tried so far is open the command line through the troubleshooter:

[image: Command Prompt]

I am then able to get into the command line as the admin so I can now run Administrative commands, so I run this:

```
X:\windows\system32>regedit
```

That opens up the Registry editor, and I can change the value back to `1`, but when I exit the Registry Editor,  and restart the computer and look at that value once logged in, it didn't change, it is still set to `0`. Do I need to save upon exiting registry editor somehow? Why isn't it committing it and using that value upon reboot?

Comment: You will need to log into an Administrator user in order to do what you describe.

Comment: The account I am using is in the Administrator Group, if that is what you mean, but it isn't the Actual Administrator

Comment: Domain or local profile, domain trumps local permissions.

Comment: Domain. How come I was able to switch it to `0` then?

Comment: Have you really though?  You indicate you are changing it, rebooting, and it hasn't actually changed.  You didn't answer the question if the account is a domain user or not.

Comment: I answered in the comment above, that it is a Domain. I was able to change it to `0`, restart and it stayed, but I can't change it back to `1` (logging in normally). I can change it by logging into the troubleshooter and opening it from the command line as an admin, but then when I restart it is still `0`, so it didn't save the change

Comment: I am confused.  Your question makes zero references to the word *Domain*.  It says you are an `Administrator`, but often times I have found people say they are an `Administrator`, and in reality they are logging into a Domain user and have local `Administrator` permissions.  It sounds like you are not `Administrator` on the Domain, which means the group policy surrounding the UAC, will override **ALL** changes.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what your asking. I am a Local Administrator logged in on a Domain.

Comment: @Ramhound I figured it out, I just needed to login as an older user who had the rights to this.